# The value of the series $\frac11+\frac1{2+3}+\frac1{4+5+6}+\cdots$ and $\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2\cdot3}+\frac{1}{4\cdot5\cdot6}+\cdots$

Tags: sequences-and-series, closed-form

What is the value of the sum of the series

$$\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2+3}+\frac{1}{4+5+6}+\cdots\;?$$

And this:

$$\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2\cdot3}+\frac{1}{4\cdot5\cdot6}+\cdots\;?$$

Comment: Do you always add one more term in the denominator? In which case the next term would be $\frac{1}{7+8+9+10}$?

Comment: There are two close votes. I vote against closing. The question was merely formulated ungrammatically; it's a real question and the grammar has been fixed in the meantime.

Comment: FWIW: the denominators of your second series are in the [OEIS](http://oeis.org/A057003); the series itself does not seem to have a neat closed form.

Comment: Same question, many years later, at MathOverflow, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/443247/whats-this-infinite-sum

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note $a+(a+1)+\cdots+(b-1)+b= (b-a+1)(b+a)/2$. Set $b=n(n+1)/2,a=n(n-1)/2+1$:
$$(\circ)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left((n(n+1)/2-[n(n-1)/2+1]+1)\cdot\frac{n(n+1)/2+[n(n-1)/2+1]}{2}\right)^{-1}$$
$$=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{2}{n(n^2+1)}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac{2}{n}-\frac{1}{n+i}-\frac{1}{n-i}\right)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\int_0^12x^{n-1}-x^{n+i-1}-x^{n-i-1}dx$$
$$=\int_0^1\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^{n-1}\right)(2-x^i-x^{-i})dx=\int_0^1\frac{1-x^i}{1-x}dx+\int_0^1\frac{1-x^{-i}}{1-x}dx$$
$$=\psi(1+i)+\psi(1-i)+2\gamma.$$
(Where $\psi$ is the [digamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function).) That's the first series. Second one doesn't look so easy.

Answer (score 3):

There is a simple formula for $\sum_{i=k}^n i = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}-\frac{(k-1)k}{2}$.

Now, the m-th denominator has $m$ terms, which means that there are $1+2+..+(m-1)=\frac{(m-1)m}{2}$ terms before the first of the denominator.

Hence, your n'th term is

$$\frac{1}{\sum_{i=\frac{(n-1)n}{2}+1}^{\frac{(n-1)n}{2}+n} i}$$

Use the formula at the begining of the proof, and you'll probably end up with a standard telescopic sum....

**Edit** See Andre's comment below, this is not telescopic, so read the above comments as "how to reduce this series to a simpler "closed" form series".. The exact formula is calculated below by Andre.

Comment: For the first question, we are looking at $\sum\frac{2}{n(n^2+1)}$.  There is an exotic closed form, but no easy telescoping.

Comment: It was clear that we should end up with a cubic in the denominator, I was expecting omne which is a product of three linear (mainly because I was expecting this to be an exam/assignment type question), but too lazy to calculate it.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: You can write it nicely in terms of the logarithmic derivative of the gamma function.  is this the exotic form?

Comment: @Eric Naslund: Yes. Exotic is relative, to you it  is roughly as familiar as $x^2$.